# On select of dropdown value, the corresponding appropriate value should be populated in textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On select of dropdown value, the corresponding some appropriate value should be displayed in textbox. How to do this in Angular js? Like I have dropdown:

```
<select class="input-medium" ui-select2 name="affiliate" required ng-model="payout.affiliate.id" required gt-input-msg gt-error-msgs="gtErrorMsgs">
<option></option>
<option ng-repeat="s in affiliateList" value ={{s.id}}>{{s.affiliateName}}</option>
 </select>
```

On select of any value I should be able to display property affiliate.points in some other div or textbox.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the ngChange directive on the select element like so:

```
<select ng-model="selectedAffiliate" ng-change="GetAffiliatePoints(selectedAffiliate)"></select>
```

When the select value changes the selectedAffiliate property on your scope is updated to hold the selected value. Then you can look up the points for that affiliate and display them somewhere.